# Faster way to group data than pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, performance, pandas-groupby, genetic-algorithm

I am implementing a Genetic Algorithm. For this algorithm a number of iterations (between 100 to 500) have to be done where in each iteration all 100 individuals are evaluated for their 'fitness'. To this extent, I have written an evaluate function. However, even for one iteration evaluating the fitness of the 100 individuals already takes 13 seconds. I have to speed this up massively in order to implement an efficient algorithm.

The evaluate function takes two arguments, and then performs some calculations. I will share part of the function since a similar form of calculation is repeated after that. Specifically, I now perform a groupby to a dataframe called df_demand, and then take the sum of a list comprehension that uses the resulting dataframe from the groupby function and another dataframe called df_distance. A snippet of df_demand looks as follows but has larger dimensions in reality (index is just 0,1,2,...):

```
date         customer    deliveries   warehouse   
2020-10-21          A            30           1
2020-10-21          A            47           1
2020-10-21          A            59           2
2020-10-21          B           130           3
2020-10-21          B           102           3 
2020-10-21          B            95           2
2020-10-22          A            55           1             
2020-10-22          A            46           4 
2020-10-22          A            57           4
2020-10-22          B            89           3 
2020-10-22          B           104           3
2020-10-22          B           106           4
```

and a snippet of df_distance is (where the columns are the warehouses):

```
index   1     2      3       4
A       30.2    54.3   76.3   30.9
B       96.2    34.2   87.7   102.4
C       57.0    99.5   76.4   34.5
```

Next, I want to groupby df_demand such that each combination of (date, customer, warehouse) appears once and all deliveries for this combination are summed. Finally, I want to calculate total costs. Currently, I have done the following but this is too slow:

```
def evaluate(df_demand, df_distance):
    costs = df_demand.groupby(["date", "customer", "warehouse"]).sum().reset_index()
    cost = sum([math.ceil(costs.iat[i, 3] / 20) * df_distance.loc[costs.iat[i, 1], costs.iat[i, 2]] for i in range(len(costs))])

    etc... 
    return cost
```

Since I have to do many iterations and considering the fact that dimensions of my data are considerably larger, my question is: what is the fastest way to do this operation?

Comment: You don't use the arguments `demand` and `distances` in `evaluate`. What is your expected output? Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Updated the code. After calculating `cost` I do some similar calculations but I expect that if I know how to solve this I will be able to solve the other calculations as well, so I have now let the function return `cost`.

Comment: What exactly the `cost` here that you are trying to compute?

Comment: `cost` is the total cost of doing all deliveries. For each day deliveries are delivered from warehouses to customers. If a customer has multiple lines in df_demand that are appointed to the same warehouse, these can be grouped together. By dividing the total number of deliveries on a day from one warehouse to a customer by 20 we know how many truck drives are needed. The costs of one truck drive for each customer, warehouse-combination are stored in df_distance and so these are then multiplied by the number of truck drives.

Answer (score 0):

let's try:

```
def get_cost(df, df2):
    '''
    df: deliveries data
    df2: distance data
    '''
    pivot = np.ceil(df.pivot_table(index=['customer', 'warehouse'], columns=['date'], 
                           values='deliveries', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
                      .div(20)
                   )
    
    return pivot.mul(df2.rename_axis(index='customer', columns='warehouse').stack(),
              axis='rows').sum().sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This does speed up the process. However, sometimes I get an error. I believe this is because if a combination of customer and warehouse does not exist in df_demand, the pivot table has other dimensions than the stacked distances dataframe. Not all warehouses are connected to each customer so this is an issue. The error thrown is `NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented`.
Also, speed has increased but I am looking to increase it even more. Maybe I can share the rest of the code as well?